# Verifying a certificate

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, verify

I am trying to validate a certificate I got from Apple with their own intermediate and root certificate. This is what I do and the answer I get:

```
c:\dev\OpenSSL-Win64\bin>openssl.exe verify -CAfile k:\MDM\AppleIncRootCertificate.pem k:\MDM\AppleWWDRCA.pem k:\MDM\mdm_public.pem
k:\MDM\AppleWWDRCA.pem: OK
k:\MDM\mdm_public.pem: UID = NQLH5GG9T6, CN = MDM Vendor: E A/S, OU = E A/S, O = E A/S, C = DK
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Does anyone have an explanation or solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way I use `openssl verify` which is incorrect. The certificate chain needs to be concatenated in a file (AppleIncRootCertificate.pem and AppleWWDRCA.pem) and the correct use is like this:

```
openssl.exe verify -CAfile k:\mdm\cert_chain k:\MDM\mdm_public.pem
```

Which results in:

```
k:\MDM\mdm_public.pem: OK
```